# Can I internalize VSCode Extentions for my company

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

Sadly we dont have direct access to the internet in my company. We can handle automatically downloading and packaging VSCode itself using our internal chocolatey but but providing extentions is still a big problem. Partly because they install into the user directory.

Is there a way I can either:

a) Internalize vscode extentions, like a setting that points to an internal nuget server (much like the full visual studio gallery)

b) Place extentions on a pc in some system level location. Eg C:\ProgramData\VSCode\Extentions and then we can install extentions for all users on a given computer using chocolatey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private extension galleries are not supported as of VSCode 1.13 but we are tracking the feature request here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21839

You can manually install and share extensions as vsix files though. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_common-questions for details